# Cant run php/mysql script on terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal, mysql-error-2002

Im having the hardest time with this. Im doing a simple select statement in php through terminal. I can run this script in my browser by refreshing the page just fine. But when i type

`php test.php`

on the terminal, it returns

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock)`

I dont think theres anything wrong with the script itself, but im not sure what the error message is telling me or what i should do about it. Thanks1

Answer (score 0):

Try host `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` or pass absolute path to the `mysql.sock`:

```
$port = '/path/to/mysql.sock';
```